# What is the use of $$ sign in table name in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I get to maintain a application which use $$ sign as prefix and suffix to some word in the table create statement - Oracle DB. like

> create table $$temp$$(id int)

For testing purpose I ran the statement in SQL plus but it threw invalid character error and so I had to remove $$ sign and then it ran as expected.

Is there a specific use for $$? some thing related to session ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a specific use for $$

No there is not. Dynamic performance views, however, have one dollar sign (`$`) in their names, `v$sql`, for example. It's Oracle's choice to name them that way.

You won't be able create a table, which name starts with dollar sign(`$`), simply because any non-quoted identifier should begin with an alphabetic character. You can however force Oracle to accept an identifier that begins with a non-alphabetic character if you enclose it with double quotation marks, like so

```
create table "$$temp$$"(
  id int
)
```

but it should be noted that when you created a table using double quotation marks, you made that table name case-sensitive (unless you didn't type the table name in uppercase) and would always have to use double quotation marks when referencing that table.

Answer (score 6):

You can create, and later drop, the table with nonstandard characters by using double(!) quotes around the table name: `create table "$$tmp$$"(id int)`. And no, the $ doesn't have any special meaning, except that it shouldn't be used by the user, because various internal tables have names that contain a $ (think v$session). The $ is supposed to avoid name conflicts.